# Установка Bitcoin-Abe на windows

Tags: python, bitcoin

Доброго времени суток!

Есть программа https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe . Сам являюсь разработчиком PHP и данная программа для меня является как дополнение. Не работал с Python до этого случая. При выполнении команды `python -m Abe.abe --config abe-my.conf --commit-bytes 100000 --no-serve` выходят следующие ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Program Files\OSPanel\domains\bitcoin-abe-master\Abe\abe.py", line 32, in <module>
    import DataStore
  File "Abe\DataStore.py", line 32, in <module>
    import Chain
  File "Abe\Chain\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .. import deserialize, BCDataStream, util
  File "Abe\deserialize.py", line 11, in <module>
    from util import short_hex, long_hex
  File "Abe\util.py", line 24, in <module>
    import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as SHA256
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Hash.SHA256
```

Может кто-нибудь подсказать где можно найти полный мануал по установке этой прекрасной программы на Windows?

Comment: похоже вам не хватает `Crypto.Hash.SHA256` . Попробуйте поискать как его установить

Comment: @Viktorov сделал всё как было указано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588065) . Однако, ошибка всё равно выходит